# Wpf getting the row number of DataGrid on button click even C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have 2 buttons inside every row of DataGrid. They will be used to either save edited row info, either to delete row. But I can't retrieve the row number on click event.
(there are similar issues on stackoverflow to mine, but none worked for me)

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Height="21" Width="21" Margin="4" Style="{StaticResource InformButton}" Click="ClientSave">
                <StackPanel Height="17" Width="20">
                    <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/TimeCounter;component/resources/save.png" Height="14" Width="14" Margin="-1,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
            <Button Height="21" Width="21" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="4"  Style="{StaticResource InformButton}">
                <StackPanel Height="18" Width="21">
                    <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/TimeCounter;component/resources/delete.png" Height="14" Width="13" Margin="0 ,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
       </StackPanel>
 </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If stuck to event, I would use binding to retrieve data item, and its index.

In event handler:

```
var btn = sender as Button;
var item = btn.GetBindingExpression(Button.DataContextProperty).DataItem as YourRowItemClass;
var index = YourViewModel.ItemCollection.IndexOf(item);
```

View model:

```
class YourViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    ObservableCollection<RowItem> ItemCollection { get; private set; }
}
```

In your button XAML:

```
DataContext="{Binding}"
```

Comment: What is ViewModel? I checked the MVVM practice but dont understand to what I should refer here.

Comment: I was assuming that you are making `DataGrid` rows using `ItemsSource`. If you are not that familiar with MVVM, you still can find vast of resources about it, and may be out of scope w.r.t this question, too general.
See edit showing a sample view model code (the interface itself is not necessary for this sample, but usually accompanies).